# Excel Macro - Save As Based on Cell Reference - With Signatures

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

Seems like it should be simple enough, I know, but a couple of little complications are making this really frustrating.

The vba I'm using is this:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\Documents\General\Clients\IQA Sampling Plans\"
filename = "IQA-" & Range("D2")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

However, a couple of issues occurr:

1. I get a 400 error. I suspect it might be to do with the amount of Power queries I have running, although I have some code before this that is supposed to break all links. It doesn't harm anything though, the macro still does what it's supposed to, it's just annoying.
2. It saves it as the new document, in the new location, and gives it the new name, but when I go to close it, it insists on me saving as again. I can choose 'don't save' though, and it's fine. the real reason why this is such a pain though is because I have digital signature fields in, which can't be used until Excel has been saved into a format it can use (i.e. not an xltm). So I have to run this macro before I can use them, but then I try to use them, and it still doesn't recognise that it's an appropriate file format now. It clearly is, it's saved in the new folder, but it's only after I close it and open it again that it registers this, and I can use the signature fields. Which is then doubly annoying by having to select 'Don't Save'. I've tried to build in a 'close' and 'open' functionality into the macro, but after it's gone through this bit, the 400 error strikes, and no other lines of code run anyway.

So I'm not sure if the issues are that I'm:

1. Trying to save as from a template,
2. Using signature fileds,
3. Using Power Queries,
4. All of the above,
5. Or my code is just crap.

Any ideas?

Update: I was having a play and added some:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

(With the corresponding Trues at the end of the code obvioulsy).

And I realised that I'd just deleted the sheets witht he queries on, rather than the queries themselves, so I added these.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Query1").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Query2").Delete
```

And for one beautiful moment, it all worked as it should. The Macro ran, it left me with a new, renamed file, and I was able to sign it.

It worked about twice, and then for no particular reason, the 400 error came back. So I'm sure that's the source of my problems.

Now it's gone back to the macro running really smoothly, with a 400 error at the end, and then when I try to close it, it forces me to do a save as. It refuses to beleive that I've already done it, and changed the file format.

Update again: There is one other possibility. I've been having real problems with my OneDrive, which keeps asking me to sign in every time I try to open the newly created file. POssibly because I have several accounts running. It could be a weird conflict with me not being properly logged into the onedrive I'm trying to save it into at that moment in time. It still appears in the OneDrive folder. But that could have soemthing to do with it. It's been causing me a headache all day.

Comment: just checking, are you trying to save the file with the Macro in it as a non macro enabled file from the macro?  or is the activeworkbook a different book?  feel like this has a fairly large impact on peoples replies

Comment: I'm trying to save it as a non-macro enable workbook. A bog stadard .xlsx. The rest of the code actually strips out all the formulas, queries and macros and leaves it as a very boring file just waiting for soemone to sign it off.

Comment: Couple of thoughts: 1) you mention xltm. The standard work flow should be  a) create a new workbook based on the template (which would be unsaved, unnamed, untyped) b) saveas that workbook to the location and type you choose.  You should get a warning you're about to loose your vba.  But it won't actually be gone until you close and reopen.  2) if your workflow requires you to be working with a master flie, try [`SaveCopyAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) 3) it might be better to seperate your code from the data, using an AddIn

Comment: i think @chrisneilsen has given you the answer of how to solve.  i believe the issue is you are saving as non macro enabled but it has a macro in it so it is then asking you to save as because it isn't fully saved, as the macro hasn't been saved

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen. Opening the template has already, but default, renamed the document, just waiting for me to save it somewhere. I think I definitley need to be workin with that master file, as it's got all the connections and formulas in it. By the time I save it as an xlsx, everything in stripped out of it. I think I might have craked it though (see below), in the end I think it's just my One Drive that has been causing me all these headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it!!! Definitely a OneDrive issue.

I eventually got the answer here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cached-credentials-have-expired-please-sign-in/13144055-8916-4e6e-9a0a-6e276bb565db

I deleted my credentials, as the first answer suggested. But with no luck. Un-checking 'Use Office to sync files I open' did the trick though.

Just means I'm sacraficing the ability to collaborate on my files, which still isn't ideal, but a step in the right direction.